# error GBF4691A2: No named parameter with the name 'Icons'

Tags: flutter, dart, dropdown

Hey guys i'm trying to run my code but i'm getting an error said " error GBF4691A2: No named parameter with the name 'icon'.'"

This is my code:
Try so many way to do but still get the error from that please help me

```dart
 .map((item) => DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                            value: item,
                                            child: Text(
                                              item,
                                              style: const TextStyle(
                                                fontSize: 14,
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                color: Colors.black,
                                              ),
                                              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                            ),
                                          ))
                                      .toList(),
                                  value: selectedIssue,
                                  onChanged: (value) {
                                    setState(() {
                                      selectedIssue = value as String;
                                    });
                                  },
                                  icon: const Icon(
                                    Icons.arrow_forward_ios_outlined,
                                  ),
```

Is anyone can help me to fix it?

Comment: 1.`flutter clean` and rebuilding the app. 2.you can try upgrading flutter if you've made changes on source-code

Comment: Still get the same error

Comment: could be syntax issue on your code, force upgrade will be `flutter upgrade --force`

Comment: still same  No named parameter with the name 'icon'. [D:\Flutter\flutter_windows_3.7.7-stable\luxtronic_mobile\build\windows\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]

Comment: can you provide full snippet on gist/repo, also the flutter version you are using

Comment: I'm using Flutter (Channel stable, 3.10.1. how I can give you ?

Comment: You can share your github repository. Can you include what widget are you using before `...map((item)`, I cant find any breaking changes like this .

Comment: https://github.com/nevejr/Luxctronic-.git that's the rrepository

Comment: Can you please fix all the error at my project ? thank you

Comment: Tried to run but have some Gradle issue on my side, as  for project flutter/lib seems ok,

Comment: Still same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DropdownMenuItem` does not have a parameter called `Icons`, but it has `icon`.

You misspelled it somehow.

Simply change `Icons: const Icon()` to `icon: const Icon()`

Comment: I still same error  No named parameter with the name 'Icon'

Comment: please edit your question to show the full proper code, also 'icon' not 'Icon'